# htaccess query string removal

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having following URL:

```
http://www.efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014
```

And I am using the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /film.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which rewrites my url to:

```
http://www.efilmsworld.com/blended-film-2014.html
```

Until this point it’s fine. But the problem is i have both working URLs and it duplicate the contents which is not good:

```
efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014
efilmsworld.com/blended-film-2014.html
```

So I need to remove query string url such as:

```
efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014
```

Comment: Well, you could add another RewriteRule that makes an external redirect to the “correct” version, using a RewriteCond before it to check the query string … but if “double content” form a search engine’s point of view is your main concern, then specifying a canoncial URL within your HTML document will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, kindly elaborate more as i am very new in htaccess and limited knowledge of RewriteEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /film\.php\?url=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2.html? [R=301,L]
```

to your htaccess will solve that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /film\.php\?url=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /film.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What will happen is

1. if `efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014` is entered then the url will get rewritten to `efilmsworld.com/blended-film-2014.html` and then silently rewritten (i.e. the url in address bar doesn't change) back to `efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014` so the content is still shown.
2. if `efilmsworld.com/blended-film-2014.html` is entered, it is silently rewritten to `efilmsworld.com/film.php?url=blended-film-2014` (this you were doing already.
3. the `[R=301]` flag tells browsers (and search engines) that the url has changed and can now be found at `sometitle.html`. That page is now only shown once, so no more duplicate content.

EDIT: As per comment request.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /video\.php\?url=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /video/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)\.html$ /video.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dear Howlin, i have one other issue relevant to that i am rewriting "http://www.efilmsworld.com/video.php?url=blended-film-2014" as "http://www.efilmsworld.com/video/blended-film-2014.html" kindly let me know how i can combine for this also same same "film page"

Comment: Thanks for the great help, now everything is fine.